# Why does Debian not include POSIX-specified commands like bc and ed by default?

Tags: debian, command, posix

[POSIX.1-2001](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/) [Utilities](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/idx/utilities.html) and [POSIX.1-2008](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) [Utilities](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/utilities.html) both list the commands `bc` and `ed` to be part of POSIX.

Yet, in a brand new Debian installation (version 10 for example), these commands are missing by default:

```
$ bc
bash: bc: command not found
$ ed
bash: ed: command not found
```

Why does Debian not include these commands by default? Of course, I can install them with and I did that.

```
apt-get install bc ed
```

The `bc` binary is only 87K in size. The entire package including the man page and documentation is only 209K in size.

Similarly the `ed` binary is only 55K in size. The entire package is only 93K in size.

What good reason is there not to include these tiny packages even though they are specified in POSIX?

Comment: When you installed the system, one of the prompts was to install software collections. One of those was something like "standard utilities" or "standard operating system". Did you select that?

Comment: @D.SM Yes, I did select that.

Comment: While `bc` could really be seen as less important, but it is part of the base interfaces. `ed` is really important as it is frequenly used by shell scripts. Which release are you using?

Comment: @schily Debian 10.0 (buster)

Comment: If anyone is interested, here is a discussion on this topic on the Debian user mailing list: https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2020/09/msg00334.html

Comment: @LoneLearner  Ubuntu 16.4 seems to include both. Is Debian 10.0 newer?

Comment: @schily I believe Debian and Ubuntu projects make different packaging decisions about what should go into the default install (i.e., the default install from CD or DVD iso images). So what Ubuntu includes by default has no bearing on what Debian includes by default.

Answer (score 2):

Debian doesn’t aim for strict POSIX conformance in general. Some of the tools mandated by POSIX are, in practice, not that commonly used, and therefore they aren’t included in [the “standard” Debian installation](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-archive.html#priorities).

For most of these tools this situation has evolved over time, so one can find traces of their demotion; see [this bug requesting `ed`’s](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=416585) for example.

Tools that aren’t “essential” in Debian must be explicitly mentioned in the dependencies of other packages which need them, and that also provides some measure of their “popularity”; `ed` is used by very few packages in Debian, `bc` by somewhat more. As a result, `bc` does end up being installed in many configurations.

Answer (score -2):

The simple answer is not everyone needs those utilities.

For example, I might deploy an application via Docker that uses Debian as the base OS. In this case I need very few parts of the base OS. For example, the vast majority of Python web applications do not need either bc or ed.

There are other operating systems that follow different philosophies. OpenBSD for example is intended by its developers to be installed "completely". These days they want to install, for example, a complete X environment on all systems. There are users who would rather not have X on headless servers.

Note that according to [this](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/compatibility.en.html) Debian does not claim complete POSIX compatibility.